# create a log in with javascript and html.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a log in with javascript and html. I use prompt when someone create a new user and password. I would like to know how to save the created password and user locally.

My code works but when I close the web browser, you have to create another username and password each time you want to come back to the website. I need to have something that will save the created password and username that the user create with prompt. This user and password will be use for the log in even if we close the web page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you only want to save a user locally? If you saved the user in a database for example you wouldn't need to create a new user each time

Comment: Is the web page hosted locally, i.e. only usable by one machine? Is it a public computer?

Comment: Using a PHP framework like CodeIgniter or perhaps Wordpress would have user authentication/authorization built in

Comment: ok, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that locally (I hope this is for entertainment purposes only because what you are doing is clearly not secure) would be to store it as a `cookie`.

I recommend checking out this nice stackoverflow post talking about setting and unsetting cookies with `jquery`. [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: No, it's just for fun. I try to make a football pool with log in.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLambert well then what you are doing is very insecure. It won't be a true "log in", because anyone that knows how to look at your JS file can hack their way through. For people to access your website, you need to put it on a server. So if you have an apache server with php installed then you can create a quick log in system.